# HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name is null after setting custom principal in GrantResourceOwnerCredentials in my owin authorization provider

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, oauth

Here is my GrantResourceOwnerCredentials method:

```
public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
        context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { "*" });

        AccountModels.UserProfile user = ApplicationUserManager.UserLogin(new AccountModels.LoginModel { UserName = context.UserName , Password = context.Password, RememberMe= false });

        if (user == null)
        {
            context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            if (user.IsLoggedIn = false)
            {
                context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user is no longer active. Please contact support for account activation");
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);
                identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, context.UserName));
                identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, user.UserRole));


                var roles = new string[] {user.UserRole};

                AuthenticationProperties properties = CreateProperties(user.UserName, roles, user.IsEmilConfirmed);
                AuthenticationTicket ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(identity, properties);

                context.Validated(ticket);

                MyCustomPrincipal newUser = new MyCustomPrincipal(user.UserName);
                newUser.Id = user.UserID;
                newUser.Email = user.UserName;
                newUser.Role = user.UserRole;

                SetPrincipal(newUser);
                context.Request.Context.Authentication.SignIn(identity);

            }
        }
    }
```

I had to implement a custom login logic to support my old database schema and after login i wanted to set the just logged in user in httpcontext.current.user.

Here is my SetPrincipal method:

```
private static void SetPrincipal(IPrincipal principal)
    {
        Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;
        if (HttpContext.Current != null)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.User = principal;
        }
    }
```

After authorization whenever i call HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name in a controller i get null value. What am i missing here? Can anyone give me any idea?

Answer (score -1):

Try using the `User` object in your controller:

```
var principal = User as ClaimsPrincipal;
```

Side note: call to `SetPrincipal` is not necessary in the GrantResourceOwnerCredentials if you are using OWIN hosting.

Comment: Please explain what do you mean by don't call setprincipal on startup. Setprincipal is called in GrantResourceOwnerCredentials method.

Comment: My bad, most likely that was not related to you issue nor I worded it properly. I made a correction.